# How to measure number of running workflows in cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I'd like to monitor in Prometheus number of cadence workflows currently running.

I checked metrics which are exported by different cadence services (like `cadence_history`, `cadence_worker`, `cadence_frontend` and so on) and the only workflows-related metrics I could find were:

- `activity_end_to_end_latency histogram` (`workflowType` is one of the labels)
- `workflow_success counter` / `workflow_terminate counter` / `workflow_failed counter`

So it seems that there are metrics to analyze already completed workflows, but no information about current ones. Am I right or I missed something?

It means that I have to export needed metrics on my own and I see 2 possible solutions:

- create a gauge and increment/decrement it when on start and stop of my workflow, for example:

```
func MyWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context) error {
    mymetrics.gauge.Inc()

    if err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, someActivity).Get(ctx, nil); err != nil {
        mymetrics.gauge.Dec()
        return err
    }

    // ...

    mymetrics.gauge.Dec()
    return nil
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that workflows terminated manually by the user will not be measured correctly.

- create a prometheus exporter and use `cadence.client.ListOpenWorkflow` function to collect number of running workflows. However, the cadence docs says that "heavy usage of this API may cause huge persistence pressure", so I suppose that's a very bad idea to call it inside a prometheus exporter.

Do you see any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

> So it seems that there are metrics to analyze already completed workflows, but no information about current ones. Am I right or I missed something?

That's right. There is no metrics like that emitted.

> However, the cadence docs says that "heavy usage of this API may cause huge persistence pressure"

That's not true if you use [Advanced Visibility](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/search-workflows/#introduction) with ElasticSearch.

But if using Advanced Visibility, you should use "CountWorkflowExecution" API instead. This will be more efficient to count the open workflows.

If using basic visibility, it could be a perf problem to persistence if the number is ver large. Because you have to iterate over pages to get the number.